# Checking server every 5 minutes

Tags: java, android

I saw 2 approaches to check a server in Android every X time, therefore I want to ask which way is better.

My application is requesting a HTML page from a server.

First option, is to run a service with sleep time of 5 minutes. 
Second option, to set an alarm manager with interval time of 5 minutes that triggers a broadcast reciver.

Glad if you can tell me which way is better, or if there is a better way.

Thank you.

Comment: Do you need to do do that only when app is visible to user? I would suggest to give a try with https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/network-manager

Comment: Why not just ping the server? You can use a scheduler like Quartz or cron4j to implement your 5 minutes sleep time.

Comment: Use a ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor

Comment: No, it's a background task that checks the content of a page. It's should be on the background.

Comment: @guybenhemo Fist of all, do not use `sleep`, as it is bad practise. Second, consider drawbacks of pulling server every `x` minutes: *Battery draining*. Then if you are good with that, go with `AlarmManager` (need to check `network`) or `GcmNetworkManager` (no need to check network availability)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest using `AlarmManager` and set alarms every 5 minutes and use a `BroadcastReceiver` to get the message.

My reason is that when you run your service in the background, if OS needs more resources it will kill your service and get its resources for other apps but with Alarms you reduce the risk of killing your app.

Regarding checking server, you should consult [this](http://developer.android.com/training/efficient-downloads/efficient-network-access.html) manual. just a single poll request to the server will make your radio active for at least 30s and will consume your battery. So maybe you should reconsider your intervals or even your strategy.

One other note: If you are just checking the server for new data and want to be informed if something has changed you can use [Cloud Messaging](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/). You can do most of the processing in the cloud and just send the important data back to the device(s). It is more efficient

Comment: What is better?  Using alarm manager with interval of 5 minutes, or set the alarm mangar every 5 minutes?

Comment: @guybenhemo sets the alarm to go off repeatedly in 5 minutes intervals

Answer (score 1):

i agree with @Pooya. Also you should implement a boot receiver so that your alarm will be set if the phone is rebooted. Here is the sample app that i downloaded from http://developer.android.com/shareables/training/Scheduler.zip